Can you help me open BIOS after installing elementary?
I installed elementary OS 7.1 from a bootable USB drive. I wrote over the Windows 10 that was on the PC as I had no intention of going back to it.The OS runs great, wacom works, printer works, USB wifi works and my Apple Cinema Display, keyboard and mouse all work great. However it's not recognising an internal 500gb HDD on sata2. I've tried accessing the BIOS to see if I can see it there but no matter what I try the BIOS will not launch. Motherboard boot screen say DEL for BIOS and F8 for boot menu but neither work. I've tried using an HP keyboard to see if that works but still no access. When pressing the button I get a long string of messages that, I assume, details the the system booting up. I can see a message that says "Finished GRUB failed boot detection." which appears to be the only thing with the word "fail" in it.
Can anyone help? I can copy paste Terminal commands if that helps.
Thanks
Al
Specs:
ASUS M5A 78L-M LX motherboard
Quad core AMD Athlon ii x4 640
NVIDIA GeForce GT 610
4GB memory
256GB storage
Firmware: OCZ-VERTEX450

You can try with CLI command systemctl reboot --firmware-setup and see if that works.
Just recently, after 20 years of using Linux, for the first time, I experienced not being able to enter the BIOS setup. It turned out it has something to do with GRUB and reinstalling the system fixed the issue, so if my first suggestion doesn't work try that.

I get the message:Cannot indicate to EFI to boot into setup mode: Firmware does not support boot into firmware I'll need to figure out if I can re-install from the USB. If the Function keys are not working I'm not sure.

I've tried accessing the boot menu (F8) to reinstall from the USB but that isn't working either. Anything else I can try?

You can boot the system and using 'sudo dd ...' wipe your drive clean, GRUB, and everything. You can find a way to use dd here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-remove-all-partitions-data-empty-disk/

OK but if the Function keys to access the BIOS or Boot system are still not working, do I not run the risk of bricking my machine in doing that?

We don't know if Fn keys cannot give you BIOS because of the GRUB or the BIOS itself is corrupt, or the keyboard is malfunctioning, or something else. If you do 'dd' you can at least start eliminating them. Yes, it can make your life difficult but isn't it already with this situation?

Fair enough. I was hoping there might be a way that didn't involve a full reset. I'm gonna take the drive out and reformat it on another machine and see if it shows up then. If not, I'll give the dd a spin :fingers crossed:

I've managed to format and mount the HDD using a USB>SATA cable but when I put it back inside with a SATA cable it's still not showing.  Looks like I'm going to be doing the full reset to get BIOS back :-(
